# Are these solutions correct? (If the n-value is x, will the sum be y?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, solution-verification

$$\sum_{k=5}^{(n-1)-1\times \frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}} (n-k) \times \frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}$$

All *n*-values smaller or equal to the *k*-value are to be ignored.

**if**
$$n=6$$

$$ans =1 $$

**if**
$$n=7$$ $$ans=2$$

**if**
$$n=8$$
$$ans=4$$

**if**
$$n=9$$ $$ans=6$$

That's enough for the first one. Below is the second one.

$$\sum_{k=6}^{(n-1)-1 \times \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}} \biggr((n-k)\times\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\biggl)\times2-1$$

**if**
$$n=7$$ $$ans=1$$
**if**
$$n=8$$ $$ans=3$$

**if**

$$n=9$$ $$ans=6$$

**if**
$$n=10$$ $$ans=10$$

So, are the answers correct given the *n*-values? I am pretty confident in these, but I can't be too sure, because I'm quite new to precalculus, my calculator is a bit basic and I've never had a precalculus class. So, if any of you could check if these answers are correct, I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are

First sum
$$s_n=\sum _{k=5}^{(n-1)-\frac{1}{2} \left(1-(-1)^n\right)} \frac{1}{2} \left(1-(-1)^k\right) (n-k)$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|r}
 n & s_n \\
\hline
 6 & 1 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 8 & 4 \\
 9 & 6 \\
 10 & 9 \\
 11 & 12 \\
 12 & 16 \\
 13 & 20 \\
 14 & 25 \\
 15 & 30 \\
\end{array}
$$
general formula $$s_n=\frac{1}{8} \left(2 n^2-16 n+(-1)^n+31\right)$$

---

Second sum
$$t_n=\sum _{k=6}^{(n-1)-\frac{1}{2} \left((-1)^n+1\right)} \left(\frac{2}{2} \left(\left((-1)^k+1\right) (n-k)\right)-1\right)$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|r}
 n & t_n \\
\hline
 7 & 1 \\
 8 & 3 \\
 9 & 5 \\
 10 & 9 \\
 11 & 13 \\
 12 & 19 \\
 13 & 25 \\
 14 & 33 \\
 15 & 41 \\
\end{array}
$$
general formula
$$t_n=\frac{1}{4} \left(2 n^2-24 n+(-1)^n+75\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do this! I wonder, how does one deduce the general formula from the sigma function? Is there methodologies for this?

Comment: @A.Kvåle Sure! I used *Mathematica* because it is quite tricky to do by hand

Comment: Didn't see your response until now for some reason :) I will check out Mathematica, because I currently have an even bigger monster of a sigma function I need to verify *yelp*

Comment: Try and send. I have fun with sums

Comment: I will in a little while, it still needs a lot of working :) I may send it tonight or tomorrow.